# OpenGL ES : How to use VAOs together with glVertexAttribPointer?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, opengl-es

I am trying to update the following code, using VAOs :

```
fun onSurfaceCreated() {
    // ...

    // Coordinates Handle
    this.meshCoordinatesHandle = GLES31.glGetAttribLocation(program, "mesh_coordinates")
    GLES31.glEnableVertexAttribArray(this.meshCoordinatesHandle)

    // Color Handle
    this.colorHandle = GLES31.glGetUniformLocation(program, "color")
    GLES31.glEnableVertexAttribArray(this.colorHandle)
}

fun onDrawFrame() {
    // ...

    // Mesh A
    GLES31.glVertexAttribPointer(this.meshCoordinatesHandle, 3, GLES31.GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * 4, this.meshACoordinatesBuffer)
    GLES31.glUniform4fv(this.colorHandle, 1, this.meshAColor, 0)
    GLES31.glDrawElements(GLES31.GL_LINES, this.meshALinesBuffer.capacity(), GLES31.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, this.meshALinesBuffer)

    // Mesh B
    GLES31.glVertexAttribPointer(this.meshCoordinatesHandle, 3, GLES31.GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * 4, this.meshBCoordinatesBuffer)
    GLES31.glUniform4fv(this.colorHandle, 1, this.meshBColor, 0)
    GLES31.glDrawElements(GLES31.GL_LINES, this.meshBLinesBuffer.capacity(), GLES31.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, this.meshBLinesBuffer)
}
```

I got this far, but i'm stuck here :

```
fun onSurfaceCreated() {
    // ...

    GLES31.glGenVertexArrays(2, vaos, 0)

    // VAO A
    GLES31.glBindVertexArray(vaos[0])

    GLES31.glGetAttribLocation(program, "mesh_coordinates").also {
    GLES31.glEnableVertexAttribArray(it)
    GLES31.glVertexAttribPointer(it, 3, GLES31.GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * 4, this.meshACoordinatesBuffer)
    }

    GLES31.glGetUniformLocation(program, "color").also {
    GLES31.glEnableVertexAttribArray(it)
    GLES31.glUniform4fv(it, 1, this.meshAColor, 0)
    }

    // VAO B
    GLES31.glBindVertexArray(vaos[1])

    GLES31.glGetAttribLocation(program, "mesh_coordinates").also {
    GLES31.glEnableVertexAttribArray(it)
    GLES31.glVertexAttribPointer(it, 3, GLES31.GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * 4, this.meshBCoordinatesBuffer)
    }

    GLES31.glGetUniformLocation(program, "color").also {
    GLES31.glEnableVertexAttribArray(it)
    GLES31.glUniform4fv(it, 1, this.meshBColor, 0)
    }
}

fun onDrawFrame() {
    // ...

    // Mesh A
    GLES31.glBindVertexArray(vaos[0])
    GLES31.glDrawElements(GLES31.GL_LINES, this.meshALinesBuffer.capacity(), GLES31.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, this.meshALinesBuffer)

    // Mesh B
    GLES31.glBindVertexArray(vaos[1])
    GLES31.glDrawElements(GLES31.GL_LINES, this.meshBLinesBuffer.capacity(), GLES31.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, this.meshBLinesBuffer)
}
```

Any idea where the problem could come from ?
Do I have to replace **glVertexAttribPointer** by **glBindBuffer** and **glBufferData** ?

Comment: Uniforms are stored in the default uniform block of the currently installed program. A uniforms is not a state of the VAO. Uniforms are part of the program, but not part of the attributes. If you want to organize the uniforms you can use [Uniform Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Objects) or [Shader Storage Buffer Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniforms are stored in the default uniform block of the currently installed program. A uniforms is not a state of the VAO. Uniforms are part of the program, but not part of the attributes. If you want to organize the uniforms you can use [Uniform Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object) or [Shader Storage Buffer Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object).

Set the uniform before drawing the mesh:

```java
fun onSurfaceCreated() {
    // [...]

    GLES31.glGenVertexArrays(2, vaos, 0)

    // VAO A
    GLES31.glBindVertexArray(vaos[0])
    GLES31.glGetAttribLocation(program, "mesh_coordinates").also {
       GLES31.glEnableVertexAttribArray(it)
       GLES31.glVertexAttribPointer(it, 3, GLES31.GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * 4, this.meshACoordinatesBuffer)
    }

    // VAO B
    GLES31.glBindVertexArray(vaos[1])
    GLES31.glGetAttribLocation(program, "mesh_coordinates").also {
       GLES31.glEnableVertexAttribArray(it)
       GLES31.glVertexAttribPointer(it, 3, GLES31.GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * 4, this.meshBCoordinatesBuffer)
    }
}

fun onDrawFrame() {
    // [...]

    // Mesh A
    GLES31.glGetUniformLocation(program, "color").also {
       GLES31.glUniform4fv(it, 1, this.meshAColor, 0)
    }
    GLES31.glBindVertexArray(vaos[0])
    GLES31.glDrawElements(GLES31.GL_LINES, this.meshALinesBuffer.capacity(), GLES31.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, this.meshALinesBuffer)

    // Mesh B
    GLES31.glGetUniformLocation(program, "color").also {
       GLES31.glUniform4fv(it, 1, this.meshBColor, 0)
    }
    GLES31.glBindVertexArray(vaos[1])
    GLES31.glDrawElements(GLES31.GL_LINES, this.meshBLinesBuffer.capacity(), GLES31.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, this.meshBLinesBuffer)
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to set the color uniform when configuring the VAOs? (meshAColor and meshBColor are FloatArray(4))

Comment: @Denis No it is not. You need 1 color attribute for each vertex coordinate. In your case the color is not an attribute, you have a uniform color for the whole mesh. However, as suggested, you can create one [Uniform Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object) or [Shader Storage Buffer Objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object) per mesh. The UBO or SSBO can be pre-initialized and just needs to be bound when the mesh is drawn.

Comment: @Denis You cannot Link the UBO to the VAO. You cannot link Attributes and Uniformen.